# htaccess hide "Index of"

Tags: .htaccess

I want display just the directory content of my Webserver.

My .htaccess file contains:

```
Options '+Indexes'
IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
```

And in the browser I got the path :

```
"Index of /~efc/"
```

In the footer :

`"Apache/2.2.22 (FreeBSD) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1c mod_hcgi/0.9.4 DAV/2 Server"`

Is there a way to prevent these lines?

EDIT: In addition to the answer of Sàt i got my desired result with following directives:

```
Options '+Indexes'

# SET INDEX OPTIONS
IndexOptions IgnoreCase FancyIndexing FoldersFirst NameWidth=* DescriptionWidth=* SuppressHTMLPreamble

# SPECIFY HEADER FILE
HeaderName header.html

# SPECIFY FOOTER FILE
ReadmeName footer.html

# IGNORE THESE FILES
IndexIgnore header.html footer.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Use the HeaderName and ReaderName directives, like this:

```
Options '+Indexes'
IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
HeaderName fancy_hdr.html
ReadmeName fancy_readme.html
```

HeaderName points at the html file rendered before the listing, ReadmeName points at the html rendered after the listing.

There are a whole lot of fun customization options, you might want to take a look at those in the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html) or [various](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/apache/ch07_01.htm) [tutorials](http://www.superk.org/index.php/Apache_FancyIndexing).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

The footer is also printed on error pages like 404. You can control its display via the [ServerTokens](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servertokens) directive in your httpd.conf.